# The time difference is lagging by one hour - java

Tags: java, android, time

I am trying to get the time difference between two different time zones and do some kind of synchronization in my app. However, I am having a strange problem. THe time difference I am getting is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 if(msg.what == 101)
            {
             Log.v("today", server_date);

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa");  //format for string to date conversion
                Date date = null;   //string to date convert
                try {
                    date = (Date)formatter.parse(server_date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long oldtime = date.getTime();  //date to milliseconds base 1970-01-01

                Calendar nowdate = Calendar.getInstance();  //pick present time
                String now_date = nowdate.toString();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aa");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf2.format(new Date());
                Log.v("today", currentDateandTime);

                Date date1 = null;
                try {
                    date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(currentDateandTime);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               long nowtime = date1.getTime();   //convert to milli seconds

                long timediff = nowtime - oldtime;        //find difference

                long hours, mins, secs;
                hours = timediff/ (1000 * 60 * 60);
                mins = (timediff - (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
                secs = (timediff - (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60) - (mins * 60 * 1000))/ (1000);

                Log.v("today", String.valueOf(timediff));
                Log.v("today", String.valueOf(hours) + " hours " + String.valueOf(mins) + " mins " + String.valueOf(secs) + "secs");

            }
```

Below is the logcat:

```
 11-12 13:20:13.732  32691-32691/com.example.sumit.myapplication V/today﹕ server_date: 2015-11-12 14:20:15 pm
 11-12 13:20:13.732  32691-32691/com.example.sumit.myapplication V/today﹕ phone_date: 2015-11-12 13:20:13 PM
 11-12 13:20:13.732  32691-32691/com.example.sumit.myapplication V/today﹕ difference: -2000
 11-12 13:20:13.732  32691-32691/com.example.sumit.myapplication V/today﹕ 0 hours 0 mins -2secs
```

Comment: Do both timezones observe (or not) DST?

Comment: I am not sure how to know. My local device does observe the DST but I am not so sure about the server time. How do I solve it?

Comment: You don't need to do `Date date1 = formatter.parse(sdf2.format(new Date()))`. And `new Date().getTime()` can be simplified to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Also the formatter can be reused as long as the settings don't change so you shouldn't need to create more than one. If you can, let the server provide it's time in something that isn't timezone dependent, e.g. directly `System.currentTimeMillis()` or you'd need to have it send it's timezone in the date/time string as well. Worst case, assume differences starting around 15 minutes are due to timezone, because people in e.g. NZ have +12:45

Comment: But then again.. shouldn't the time difference between 2015-11-12 14:20:15 pm and 2015-11-12 13:20:13 PM be one hour no matter what.

Comment: I think you can get the timezone from the Calendar and there is a method like "getDSTOffset"

Comment: I see that the code you have posted is not the code that has written the log file entries. This may not be the code responsible for the error.

Comment: nops.. the same code generated the log cat

Comment: No, it did not, because there's strings in the log between "today﹕" and the dates which aren't in the Log.v call: server_date, phone_date etc.

Comment: Oh I see. I edited that later here for the sake of convinience to the readers. But it is the same code.

Comment: Anyway, comparing times between two systems - one of them apparently a mobile - without an indication of the time zone is not going to work. You think they are off by one hour, but just because you don't display the time zone. Sending one time as a string without the TZ is like asking me how late it is - and setting your clock to 21:05 ;-)